# Live console output in Windows Remote Shell?

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, remote-access

Windows has several built-in options to access the shell (command prompt) of a remote computer and run commands on that remote computer. This is done through the Windows Remote Management service (winrm) on the remote computer, which can be accessed from a client either through `winrs -r:<remote address>` (cmd) or `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <remote address>` (PowerShell). I've got both methods to work and can execute commands on the remote machine as if I'm sitting in front of it.

The problem is that apparently the output of the command is not displayed "live" or interactively, but only after the command has finished executing. For example, using `dir /P` on a large directory is supposed to pause after each screen of filenames and continue after a keypress. In a `winrs` session, the /P parameter is ignored and the directory listing is dumped all at once. Another example is a python script for monitoring, which runs indefinitely (until stopped manually) and updates the screen periodically (i.e. clears the screen and prints new info). When run through the remote shell, the output is not displayed while it's running, but only after I abort it manually it fetches the most recent output.

A third-party SSH connection (e.g. Bitvise SSH server and putty client) works perfectly fine with live updates while the remote command/program is running. Is there a way to have the same behavior with the built-in remote shell in Windows? I'm referring in particular to Windows 10, but it applies to older versions as well, at least going back to Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that apparently the output of the command is not displayed "live" or interactively, but only after the command has finished executing. For example, using dir /P on a large directory is supposed to pause after each screen of filenames and continue after a keypress. In a winrs session, the /P parameter is ignored and the directory listing is dumped all at once.

Those are actually two different problems.

The WinRS and PSRP protocols do have the ability to stream command output incrementally, and to [send input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wsmv/dc0ef2e9-b615-4e51-ba0e-3af737bb3b0e) back. For example, if you had used `del /p` to delete files, you *would* have seen the confirmation prompt.

What they don't provide is a *console* with well-defined width×height – instead the output is captured by a "pipe". Because of that, the `dir` command *itself* assumes that it's being run non-interactively and decides to ignore your `/p` option and to not show any prompts in the first place, similar to what you would've gotten with `dir /p > list.txt`.

*(These are two different APIs that are transported through the same WinRM connection – the 'winrs' command uses "Remote Shell" (WinRS), while Enter-PSSession uses "PowerShell Remoting" (PSRP) – but they share the same limitation in that they can only provide stream input but not full console access.)*

SSH servers, including the "OpenSSH for Windows" server that is included with Windows 10, *do* create a console for the remote program, which is what lets `ssh -t localhost "dir /p"` work – as it now knows the intention (it isn't being redirected to a file or something) and also recognizes the number of lines it needs to display per page (the SSH server configures the remote console to be of the same size as the local one).

Most program runtimes, including Python, buffer their output internally and only flush it to the OS after accumulating a certain amount. Most of them also adjust their buffering depending on what the output is connected to – just like on Linux, if Python detects that its sys.stdout is a terminal it'll use line-based buffering (flushing output as soon as a `\n` is written), but when writing to a file or a pipe it'll use block-based buffering (flushing only every 8 kB of data).

Using `print(..., flush=True)` or calling `sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)` might help in your situation, although it still won't allow the program to clear the screen or receive complex input (e.g. arrow keys). You'll still need SSH for that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You're saying full console access is not supported through WinRM and there are no special modifiers to enable it, right? I can do my remote monitoring through SSH instead, that's not a problem, just wanted to understand the limitations of going through WinRM.